# C# : Create a REST API GET method and run it to get value from URL

Tags: c#, webapi

Well I want to create a REST API with GET method, in C# :
Say : localhost:654321/getData/?id=5
and then whenever i run this in web browser it show return the relative data . id is variable.

any link / reference to such will be helpful

Thank You

Comment: This is not a teaching site, please instead use your favorite search engine to look for `"how to create a web api with c#"`. I just tried, and it gives millions of results.

Answer (score 0):

Please find a sample below. This method GetData can be invoked as below

http://localhost:81/Indicator/Param1Value/Interval/param3Value?queryParam=true

```
 [HttpGet("{param1}/{interval}/{param3}")]
        public List<MyObjects> GetData(string param1, int interval, DateTime param3,bool queryParam=false)
        {
//Implementation
}
```

An example request is

http://localhost:81/Indicator/abc/5/2021-03-30?queryParam=true

You will find lot of samples from google